# ADB is not recognizing Samsung S21 when connected with USB

Tags: android, linux, adb, samsung-mobile-sdk

When I connect the S21, it only shows information that it is charging, but no prompt for accepting the computer etc.

I am using Ubuntu.

USB debugging is active, and ADB is installed. Tried two different computers and two cables. lsusb does not show the device, neither does adb devices. Also tried adb kill-server followed by adb start-server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you enable USB Debugging from the device settings?  If so revoke all access and try again.

Comment: USB debugging is active, also tried to revoke access and repeating.

Comment: Try to change USB settings on your phone. If this not help, download and install another version of USB drivers for your device.

Comment: I installed the Samsung Android USB drivers from [here](https://developer.samsung.com/mobile/android-usb-driver.html) and things worked afterwards. I don't know if it worked before however since I also switched cables (the included USB-C to USB-C didn't even charge when connected to my laptop). You should also make sure that your adb is up to date, for example by updating the SDK Platform Tools through Android Studio (31.0.2 is the most recent at time of writing).

Comment: This video solved the problem for me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgbjX7VghVM

It has two more steps in addition to the usual:
1. Dev options -> Default USB Configuration -> Transferring Files, and
2. Enter `*#0808#` in the phone keypad, then select MTP + ADB (or MTP), disconnect the USB, reboot, and reconnect the USB.

Then the pop-up to confirm the PC showed on the phone, and `adb` started to work.

Answer (score 6):

This YouTube video helped me:
[Samsung Galaxy S21, S21 Plus and S21 Ultra USB NOT RECOGNIZE SOLUTION](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgbjX7VghVM)

It has two more steps in addition to the usual:

1. Settings -> Developer Options -> Default USB Configuration -> select Transferring Files, and
2. Enter `*#0808#` in the phone keypad, then select MTP + ADB (or just MTP), disconnect the USB, reboot the phone, and reconnect the USB.

After that, the pop-up to confirm the PC showed on the phone, and `adb` started to work.

I had also added a udev rule, created the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` with:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Then:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Comment: he tells me wrong code when I use *#0808#

Comment: These steps don't help me.  Neither S21 or S21 FE connect with Ubuntu, both with Android 12.  I tried with two cables, one older and one new, good cables though not expensive ones,  Non work with the Samsung's, though they both work well with a Huawei Android 9 phone.  I posted questions on Samsung site but can't get useful help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seams like the solution is connecting S21 to USB C port on your PC (if there is one of course).